# escape or omit binary data in backtrace buffer?

Tags: debugging, backtrace

Many times when I check the backtrace buffer, I can't copy the text out because of the embedded binary data (perhaps it's the internal null characters making the copy function think the string is shorter than it is?) so that when I try to copy the buffer with <kbd>C-x h M-w</kbd> (don't remember if those are standard bindings), only a portion of the buffer gets copied (presumably up until the internal null character).

Is there a way to escape the binary data so that I may copy the buffer in its entirety? Or is there a way to omit the binary data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There is no simple solution ready-to-hand. As far as I know, users just manually remove the bytecode from backtraces they report. That's what I do, at least.

This has been requested more than once, including with [Emacs bug #6991](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6991).

The bug was summarily closed immediately -- no reason given.  Eventually it was reopened and relegated to the "wishlist".

(You can always try again -- `M-x report-emacs-bug`, now that there is a new GNU Emacs maintainer. Dunno whether that will make a difference.)

Comment: Wow, that's surprising. Hopefully the response does change with the new maintainer. Thanks for giving me the context/history on this!

Comment: Try again. Maybe you'll have better luck. You can also try raising the issue in `emacs-devel@gnu.org`. If there is no interest you will know that right away. If there is some interest, maybe something will come of it. You never know, unless you try.